# How to export mllib als results into text file Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new in Spark. I'm trying to run a collaborative filtering algorithm and I made it. Now I want to know how can I put users recommendations into a text file or a mysql data set?

For example in my spark shell:

```
scala> topKRecs.mkString("\n")
res3: String = 
Rating(101168482,976126,17.762857135595247)
Rating(101168482,298077,15.618423165870723)
Rating(101168482,269474,15.20514216060495)
Rating(101168482,992979001,14.874869183497482)
Rating(101168482,302470001,14.794531500898763)
Rating(101168482,303592,14.779064871786169)
Rating(101168482,1538670001,13.96013790139799)
Rating(101168482,458919,13.905207127505795)
Rating(101168482,1141423,13.882807601308972)
Rating(101168482,992981003,13.844550596026654)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in 2 ways:
  1 store the rating objects ie:

```
topKRecs.saveAsObjectFile("path")
```

2 store the values as output file

```
topKRecs.map(rating => (rating.user, rating.product, rating.rating)).saveAsTextFile("path")
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but this what i get:
scala> topKRecs.map(rating => (rating.user, rating.product, rating.rating)).saveAsTextFile("/home/cloudera/recom/rec.txt")
<console>:38: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[(Int, Int, Double)]
              topKRecs.map(rating => (rating.user, rating.product, rating.rating)).saveAsTextFile("/home/cloudera/recom/rec.txt")

I think .saveAsTextFile() is a RDD class method and not for an Array class or Rating class. That's my problem.

Comment: The easy way to fix that would be to do val 

    rdd = sc.parallelize(topKRecs)

now you have an rdd which you can export.

Comment: Thx, but now i have a new problem, my idea is to take all recommendations for each user. For example i have:

val userIds = model.userFeatures.map{case (id, factor)=>(id)}
val usersId = userIds.toArray

for ( i <- 0 to 1) {
 val userItemIds = model.productFeatures.map{ case (sku, factor) =>(usersId(i), sku) }
 val userRecs = model.predict(userItemIds).collect()
 val sortedUserRecs = userRecs.sortBy(-_.rating)
 val topKRecs = sortedUserRecs.take(10)
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(topKRecs)
 rdd.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/cloudera/recom/rec.txt")
}

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is here? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: I run for 2 users only, for the first run it's all ok but when the second user is running i get an error because rec.txt file is already exist, there is a way to append text instead to try to replace it?