# Writing Out ML lib recommendations to text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using the ALS implementation in mllib (in scala) to generate product recommendations for a set of users. My ALS implementation works fine and generates ratings. I have use the line:

```
val recs = model.recommendProductsForUsers(20)
```

to create a array of 20 product recommendations for each user. This works fine and the ratings look like: 
(96,Array(Rating(96,61,1.0889034936577194E-8),Rating(96,274,7.364985542945079E-9)..)

ie it is structured as  Array[(Int, Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating])]

I need to write these recommendations to a text file. I have tried:

```
recs.saveAsTextFile("./testoutput")
```

and this runs but the output is not the numbers I  need but instead looks like it is some kind of object (rather than the text inside the object)

(87,[Lorg.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating;@28ccda46)

I know I need to use maps to convert the rating object into a text object but I cannot get any combination of maps to work correctly.I think this problem is a slightly more complex version of 
[How to export mllib als results into text file Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569251/how-to-export-mllib-als-results-into-text-file-spark) - but the solution suggested there does not work for me because I am dealing with multiple users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can solve this including creating output strings manually:

```
recs.mapValues(_.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile(somePath)
```

or converting to native Scala type like `List` or `Vector`:

```
recs.mapValues(_.toVector).saveAsTextFile(somePath)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the key was using mapValues rather than just map. Both answers work beautifully for me.

Comment: You're welcome. It could be done with `map` as well. `mapValues` makes it just shorter. The main problem is really Java - Scala interop. BTW Please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).